# why the fa icon and a are not in the same line

Tags: html, css

I am debutant at html and css. I just wanted to create my first website using html and css but in the `navbar` I found that I cant make `<a>` and `fa` icons in the same line, is there any solution please?

here is the code:

```css
   body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }
    nav{
        background-color: purple;
        height: 55px;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    
    nav a{
       text-decoration: none;
        color:white;
        margin-top:30px;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 10px
    
    }
    
    nav span{
        color: white;
        font-size: 15px
    }
    
    .fa{
        float: right;
        display: inline
    }
```

```html
<html>
        
    <head>
    <title> Web page </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
    
    </head>
    <body> 
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav>
        <a href="">Acceuil</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Types d'appareils</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Ordinateurs</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Telephones</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">O.S</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Etudes</a> 
    
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    
     
    </nav><!-- End of Navbar -->
        
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

codepen:

https://codepen.io/badis-kerdellou/pen/KKKYELJ

Thanks in advance

Comment: It floats... so it breaks a line then goes floatting to the right.

Comment: how can i make it go the right without breaking a line?

Comment: See my answer. The thing that you want. Floating left in the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

************************ ***SOLVED*** ************************

Here is your updated code.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
}
nav{
    background-color: purple;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

nav a{
    display: inline-block; /*added*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px
   /*margin-top:30px;*/
}

nav span{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px
}

.fa{
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
    
<head>
<title> Web page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body> 
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav>
    <a href="">Acceuil</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Types d'appareils</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Ordinateurs</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Telephones</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">O.S</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Etudes</a> 

<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>

 
</nav><!-- End of Navbar -->
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you very much;
is there any possibilty to change the height of fa icon

Comment: Just give font-size.

Comment: Please accept and upvote my answer if it is helpful. :)

Comment: it worked but i dont know how to accept and upvote i am new in the website

Comment: i accepted it but i don't have anough reputations to upvote your answer, i have just 11 and i need other 4 reputations

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float: right` from `.fa` and add `display: inline !important;`.

You could also apply `padding-left` if required.  Please see snippet below:

```css
body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }
    nav{
        background-color: purple;
        height: 55px;
        padding-top: 25px;
    }
    
    nav a{
       text-decoration: none;
        color:white;
        margin-top:30px;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-left: 10px;    
    }
    
    nav span{
        color: white;
        font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    .fa{
        /* updated here */  
        display: inline !important;
    }
```

```html
<html>
        
    <head>
      <title> Web page </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    </head>
    <body> 
    <!-- Navbar -->
    <nav>
        <a href="">Acceuil</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Types d'appareils</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Ordinateurs</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Telephones</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">O.S</a> <span> | </span>
        <a href="">Etudes</a>     
        <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>   
     
    </nav><!-- End of Navbar -->        
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: thank you very much;
is there any possibilty to change the height of fa icon