# Prevent float right from breaking a line

Tags: html, css

i am trying to make a html + css website, i tried to make a right float for a span (which have the class .float ) but it's breaking a line, i want to know how can i prevent it from breaking a line? i tried `display:inline-block` but no addition, full code:

```
<html>

<head>
<title> Web page </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



</head>
<body> 
<!-- Navbar -->
<nav>
    <a href="">Acceuil</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Types d'appareils</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Ordinateurs</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Telephones</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">O.S</a> <span> | </span>
    <a href="">Etudes</a> 

<a href="https://twitter.com/BadisKerdellou" class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></a>   
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/badis_kerdellou/?hl=fr" class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"></a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100041024162109" class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></a>

</nav>
<!-- End of Navbar -->

<div class="header"> 
    <br> <br>
    <span class="pad"> Soufferez vous </span> <br> <br>
    <span class="pad"> De l'utlisation </span>
    <span class="not"> exagirée </span><span class="notn">de l'internet? </span>
    <br> <br> <br> <br>
    <img src="hey2.png">

    <span class="float"> Hey </span>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

css code :

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
nav{
    background-color: purple;
    height: 55px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border-bottom: 5px solid gray
}

nav a{
    display: inline-block; /*added*/

   text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px

}

nav span{
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px
}

.fa{
    float: right;
}

.header{
    background-color: purple;
    height: 600px
}

h1{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}

.header h2,h1{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
     margin-left: 20px


}

.pad{
    color: wheat;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-size: 40px
}

.not{
    color: red;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 40px
}

.notn{
    color: wheat;
    font-size: 40px
}

.header img{
    height: 300px
}

.float{
    float: right
}

.header span{
    display: inline
}
```

codepen.io:

https://codepen.io/badis-kerdellou/pen/NWWVpLV

Comment: put it ahead in the flow, before inline-block links and eventually br  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBBGrwV

Comment: @G-Cyr Sorry i haven't understood you

Comment: take your floatting element first in the HTML flow, so next elements stands aside  see the forked https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/qBBGrwV (faudrait aussi faire un effort sur l'orthographe française... )

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm so dumb I didn't even got the problem, but obviusly `<br>` breaks the line, just put the `<span class="float"> Hey </span>` before the `<br>`, like this:

```
<div class="header"> 

<br> <br>
<span class="pad"> Soufferez vous </span> <br> <br>
<span class="pad"> De l'utlisation </span>
<span class="not"> exagirée </span><span class="notn">de l'internet? </span>
<span class="float"> Hey </span>   <!--Just moved it above the <br>-->
<br> <br> <br> <br>
<img src="hey2.png">
```

Comment: there is no br in the codepen linked . the op is a beginner still confused wit float behaviors ;) there was a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59007943/why-the-fa-icon-and-a-are-not-in-the-same-line

Comment: He deleted the br right now, there were four before